# How do I parse out only the files actual name and not the full path?

Tags: swift, parsing, swift3

I have some code that (I thought) could split a filename from its file type. For example, "filename.txt" -> ["filename, "txt"].

However, I didn't realize that when I use a dialog box to open a file name, I get the full path (rookie mistake, I know). For example, this is what my function is returning:

`filename_array: ["/home/user/Downloads/filename", "txt"]`

How do I remove the path stuff and only return the `filename` part?

Comment: [Edit] your question with some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has been trying to get rid of all the "path as string" style and migrate  them into `URL`. The path manipulation API has been removed from `String` and moved to `URL`:

```
let path = "/home/user/Downloads/filename.txt"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

let fileNameOnly  = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent   // filename
let fileExtention = url.pathExtension                               // txt
```

Or you can do it old-school style with `NSString`:

```
let path = "/home/user/Downloads/filename.txt"
let fileName = (path as NSString).lastPathComponent as NSString // filename.txt

let fileNameOnly = fileName.deletingPathExtension // filename
let fileExtension = fileName.pathExtension        // txt
```

Comment: Please enlighten us with what the recommended way is